# What is the solution for the error grub rescue/no file system found?

Tags: grub2

I am using DELL-INSPIRON 15R with a dual boot of Windows 8 and Linux Mint Olivia 15. It has been working properly since it was installed. Now, it is showing the error that "no file system found. grub rescue->" What should I do for this?

Comment: boot a live CD, mount your Linux Mint install, chroot into it and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: What is meant by chroot?

Comment: a chroot changes the effective root directory. assuming that you have your Mint install mounted at `/mnt`, you would type `chroot /mnt`. this will then open a shell (probably `sh`) in `/mnt`. the special part is that to the shell, `/mnt` seems like `/`.

Comment: @strugee For this to be successful `/proc`, `/dev`, `/dev/pts`, and `/sys/` should be mounted in the chroot. And it makes sense to do that (with `mount --bind`) before the chroot.

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes, you're right. I believe I wasn't aware that you needed those at he time I wrote that comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way to solve this issue. All you know at this point is that your computer isn't bootable.

If you've changed your BIOS settings, restore them to a known good state. If you've changed your disk configuration, restore it to a known good state.

To investigate what's going on, boot your system from a live CD or live USB. [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) is good for this. Once it's booted, you can check if your RAM is ok, check if your disk is ok, explore your partitions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once when the BIOS (for some unscrutable reason) decided to switch the order of the disks in my machine (two SATA disks). Other reasons could be a broken disk, a filesystem over which something scribbled, ... Check the [grub command manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Command_002dline-and-menu-entry-commands.html). Yes, that one should be online when you are flailing with a non-booting system...